# Left Justify Labels

Tags: margins

I've been using LaTex to write my genealogical family history research for its ability to index, reference pictures, tables, etc. This is going to be a BIG document as I already have nearly 1000 pages and I'm only working on the first branch of the tree! I've struggled with the issue of enumerating the content and need some advice.

I've used the **enumitem** package to allow me to set up the enumeration better but I'm having trouble formatting it as I'd like. I have some deeply nested items such that their label would be something like B.10.2.3.2.2.3.

I'd like to set it so that those labels are left justified and the matching text for them follows that indent. I only seem to be able to make the text all justify left and then the labels crush into the margin and off the page.

This is the problem:

[image]

How can I get the "B's" to be left justified at the margin instead of running ragged? Thank you in advance!This is what it's like now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate]{topsep=7pt,itemsep=7pt}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label*=\textbf{\Alph*}., leftmargin=*} % A, B, C
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label*=\arabic*., leftmargin=0cm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnumerate}

\item This is the first item. 
\begin{myEnumerate}
    \item This is the second item. 
    \begin{myEnumerate}
        \item This is the third item. 
        \begin{myEnumerate}
            \item This is the fourth item. 
            \begin{myEnumerate}
                \item This is the fifth item. 
                \begin{myEnumerate}
                    \item This is the sixth item. 
                    \begin{myEnumerate}
                        \item This is the seventh item. 
                        \begin{myEnumerate}
                            \item This is the eighth item. 
                        \end{myEnumerate}   
                    \end{myEnumerate}   
                \end{myEnumerate}   
            \end{myEnumerate}   
        \end{myEnumerate}   
    \end{myEnumerate}   
\end{myEnumerate}   
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small example code illustrating the problem?

Comment: Edited to reflect some sample code. I'd like all the A's to be left justified at the margin.

Comment: At the text left margin, or at the sheet left side?

Comment: At the text left margin. Sorry for not using all of the correct terminology!

Comment: I asked to be sure. And if an item content  spans over several lines, will the following lines also start at the left margin, or at a fixed distance of the left margin (independently of the level of the list)?

Comment: Ideally it would continue directly under the first word that wasn't a label. So for my example above, under the word "This" for that level's text.

Comment: That's what makes it harder…

Comment: Well I'm not "glad" it's hard but I am glad that I am not missing something obvious!! It is a request that I have not been able to find anywhere else and believe me I've searched and tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand*\mywidestlabel{M.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.}% adjust here if necessary
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\mywidestlabel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate]{topsep=7pt,itemsep=7pt}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label*=\textbf{\Alph*}., align=left, leftmargin=1.0in, labelwidth=\mylength} % A, B, C
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} % 1, 2, 3
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label*=\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=\mylength} 

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnumerate}

\item This is the first item. This is the first item. This is the first item. This is the first item. 
\begin{myEnumerate}
    \item This is the second item. This is the second item. This is the second item. This is the second item. 
    \begin{myEnumerate}
        \item This is the third item. This is the third item. This is the third item. This is the third item. 
        \begin{myEnumerate}
            \item This is the fourth item. This is the fourth item. This is the fourth item. This is the fourth item. 
            \begin{myEnumerate}
                \item This is the fifth item. 
                \begin{myEnumerate}
                    \item This is the sixth item. 
                    \begin{myEnumerate}
                        \item This is the seventh item. 
                        \begin{myEnumerate}
                            \item This is the eighth item. This is the eighth item. This is the eighth item. This is the eighth item. 
                        \end{myEnumerate}   
                    \end{myEnumerate}   
                \end{myEnumerate}   
            \end{myEnumerate}   
        \end{myEnumerate}   
    \end{myEnumerate}   
\end{myEnumerate}   
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: nested enumerate lists]